# how to serialize a Socket Class with Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET) in c#

Tags: c#, android, json, serialization, xamarin

I got a problem with serializing a class with contains a Socket:
The Class I need to serialize:

```
public class ClientSocketClass : SocketClass
{
    private int port;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    public Socket ClientSocket { get { return clientSocket; } private set
        {
            clientSocket = value;
            //clientSocket.EnableBroadcast = false;
        } 
}
```

The way I try to serialize on an Activity to pass the Objet via

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ChatWindow));
intent.PutExtra("Socket", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ClientSocket));
this.StartActivity(intent);
```

The Problem seems to be the Socket Propertie inside the ClientSocketClass or more specific the `EnableBroadcast` Propertie inside the Socket Propertie. Because Im getting an Excepion while serializing the Object:

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'EnableBroadcast' on 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.`

The EnableBroadcast is not available because it is a TCP Socket.
Does anyone can tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to serialize socket? How are you going to use the result?

Comment: a socket is a transient representation of a network communication path, they can't be serialised as they lose all meaning outside of the context they are created with, try instead serialising the data required to create the socket instead

Comment: Hi Evk, Im trying to do an Android App, on the first Activity, the user can enter some information and clicks on "connect" if a connection to my server is established (here the socket object is created), he gets to the second Activity on which he can send text messages to the server. To send the messages, he needs the same socket connection that was established on the first activity, so i thought, why doent just pass the socket connection to the second activity :-P does this make sens? ;-)

Comment: Not really :) You need to run your socket connection in background service - you cannot pass it between activities like that. You should not run it in activity at all - android will kill it when activity is destroyed. Look at background services and how to communicate to them from activities.

Comment: I will, thank you very mutch.